# Is amsmath aligned environment displaystyle by default?

Tags: amsmath, displaystyle

Is the `aligned` environment automatically `\displaystyle`? This test seems to indicate it is:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \(\begin{aligned}
    \int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)dx &= \frac{1}{\pi} \\
  \end{aligned}\)

  \(\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)dx = \frac{1}{\pi} \)
\end{document}
```

Additionally, `amsmath.sty` contains the following code:

```latex
\newcommand{\start@aligned}[2]{%
    \RIfM@\else
        \nonmatherr@{\begin{\@currenvir}}%
    \fi
    \savecolumn@ % Assumption: called inside a group
    \alignedspace@left
    \if #1t\vtop \else \if#1b \vbox \else \vcenter \fi \fi \bgroup
        \maxfields@#2\relax
        \ifnum\maxfields@>\m@ne
            \multiply\maxfields@\tw@
            \let\math@cr@@@\math@cr@@@alignedat
            \alignsep@\z@skip
        \else
            \let\math@cr@@@\math@cr@@@aligned
            \alignsep@\minalignsep
        \fi
        \Let@ \chardef\dspbrk@context\@ne
        \default@tag
        \spread@equation % no-op if already called
        \global\column@\z@
        \ialign\bgroup
           &\column@plus
            \hfil
            \strut@
            $\m@th\displaystyle{##}$%
            \tabskip\z@skip
           &\column@plus
            $\m@th\displaystyle{{}##}$%
            \hfil
            \tabskip\alignsep@
            \crcr
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm not much of a tex hacker so I can't be sure but the macro definition does include `\displaystyle`. However, I wasn't able to track this information down in the documentation. Section 3 (amsmath user guide) lists displayed equations but `aligned` is not among them.

Is there a good way to determine whether a given math environment is `\displaystyle`? Normally, I would have assumed inline math defaults to non-display but the `aligned` environment is used inside `\(\)` or `$$`.

Comment: Yes, every cell in the underlying `\halign` has `\m@th\displaysyle`, so it uses that style.

Comment: The alignment building blocks are described in Sec. 3.7 of the documentation.

Comment: There are only four math styles, \displaystyle, \textstyle, \scriptstyle and \scriptscriptstyle.  You can tell the first two apart by using \sum_1^2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code contains the piece

```
\ialign\bgroup % spaces before and after & included for clarity
       & \hfil$\m@th\displaystyle{#}$ & $\m@th\displaystyle{{}#}$\hfil \crcr
%        \____________  ____________/   \_____________  _____________/
%                     \/                               \/
%         first column specification       second column specification
```

I have deleted a lot of stuff which is irrelevant to the point; I have also introduced spaces around the ampersand `&` for clarity, though the space before it is actually important; and I have replaced `##` by a single `#`, since the doubling stems from the usual TeX rules for nested definitions. Forget the first `&` for the time being. `\ialign` is an initialized form of `\halign`, the TeX primitive for horizontal alignment (it sets the intercolumn distance to zero). The first column has the specification

```
\hfil $\m@th\displaystyle{#}$
```

which means "right-aligned, displaystyle math". Using the notation of the `array` package this would be a column specifier of the form

```
>{$\m@th\displaystyle\bgroup}r<{\egroup$}
```

The second column contains

```
$\m@th\displaystyle{{}#}$\hfil
```

which means "left-aligned, displaystyle math, and start with an empty `\mathord` atom" (important for correct spacing).

What about the first `&` in the line, which I first told to ignore? That is a TeX construct; quoting from the TeXBook (p. 241)

> Preambles often have a periodic structure, and if you put an extra `&` just before one of the templates, TeX will consider the preamble to be an infinite sequence that begins again at the marked template when the `\cr` is reached.

Therefore, this sequence of right-aligned, left-aligned columns can be repeated indefinitely. So the `aligned` environment corresponds basically to a tabular with repeating `rlrlrlrl...` columns, all in displaystyle math mode.