# When to add braces in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

In some cases where weird spacing can happen, it is recommended to add (possibly empty) braces, e.g.

- Using `\underbrace` and similar ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223908/underbrace-changing-spacing-of-operators)):

  ```latex
  \[
      { \underbrace{a}_{b} } + c
  \]
  ```
- Aligning relation symbols on the right side with `amsmath` package:

  ```latex
  \begin{align*}
          {} & a \\
      \iff{} & b
  \end{align*}
  ```

  or

  ```latex
  \begin{align*}
      a ={} & b + c + d \\
         {} & + e + f
  \end{align*}
  ```

  (Bonus question: Why don't we need to do it if we align on the left side, like `&=` instead of `& {}=`?)

*Are there any other use cases of braces in math mode one should know of?*

Comment: A brace group `{...}` constructs a sub_mlist which behaves like a mathord with regards to spacing. Personally I wouldn't use `{...}` but rather be explicit by using `\mathord{...}`.

Comment: An empty brace group `{}` will result in an empty noad node which also behaves like a mathord.

Comment: You need no empty group on the right of an alignment point `&` because the left-aligned columns already start with an empty group. I've described the working of `align` a bit in [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519513/82917). (Actually the answer is about `aligned` but the main points are the same.)

Comment: The "short" answer would be "read the whole TeXbook"...